# Retroactively convert a UCS-2 file to UTF-8 in Git

Tags: git, utf-8, ucs2

I have a file that has multiple commits in my Git repository, that is encoding in 16-bit Unicode (UCS-2), that is used by Windows.

Because of that, Git considers it a binary file, instead of a text file, and I can't see the changes that different commits made.

Is there a way to retroactively convert that file to UTF-8, i.e. rebuild the history, as if the file had always been UTF-8, and I had always been commiting it as a UTF-8 file, not a 16-bit Unicode file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To retroactively recode a file, use `git filter-branch`:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'recode utf-16..utf-8 file'
```

If you don't have `recode`, use the longer `iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 file -o file` instead. If the file doesn't exist in earlier versions of the tree, you need probably want to append `|| true` so the recoding command doesn't fail, and optionally suppress error output.

Comment: Just to note, file names are relative to the root directory of the repository, so when specifying a file, it should be `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'recode utf-16..utf-8 relative/path/to/file'`. This had me confused, initially.

Comment: FWIW - If you're working with a file generated by Windows, those are apparently usually "UCS-2 Little Endian", at least in what I'm dealing with (WER error reports) - so instead of utf-16 in the `iconv` command, you want `UCS-16LE`.

Comment: @rpavlik UTF-16 is a superset of UCS-2, sort of how UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII. (True UCS-2 is rarely used these days, since it cannot represent code points outside the BMP.) Does specifying UTF-16 actually not work in your `iconv`?

Comment: Well, using iconv as shipped with git for Windows, if I just said utf16, I got East Asian characters from a file I was expecting to be essentially ASCII. A text editor said it was UCS-2 Little endian, so I figure either no byte order mark, or that iconv incantation ignores byte order marks, because only when I explicitly specified UCS-2LE did the output work as expected.

Comment: @rpavlik Can you try specifying `UTF-16LE`? That should work at least as well as UCS-2LE, only without referring to the obsolete "UCS-2" name.